# Unable to get Second Spinner value based on first Spinner Value

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm using Two Spinners where Second Spinner Value is based on First Spinner Value.

For Example If user Select Option A in First Spinner Then Second Spinner drop down list must contain value ( ox, cow, goat ) and if user select option B, then second Spinner value must contain ( Lion, Tiger and Cheetha ).

But I'm unable to do so. On selecting any value in first spinner  value, Second Spinner always loads same value. Below is the screenshot
[image]

[image]

As you can see, In selecting any option in first spinner master or diploma...In second spinner value is same.it does not change.

Below is my Activity Code

```
 public class UploadBook extends AppCompatActivity 
        Spinner spinnerCountry,spinnerDivision,spinner_condition;
        ArrayAdapter<String> countryArray,divisionArray;

        String item = "start";

        int count = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_book);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Upload book");

            spinnerCountry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCountry);
            //implementing OnItemSelectedListener (need to override the method)
            spinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

            countryArray = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            countryArray.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            spinnerCountry.setAdapter(countryArray);

            countryArray.add("Master");

            countryArray.add("Diploma");

            countryArray.setNotifyOnChange(true);

            spinnerCountry.setSelection(0);

            spinnerDivision = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDivision);
            //implementing OnItemSelectedListener (need to override the method)
            spinnerDivision.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

            divisionArray = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            divisionArray.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            spinnerDivision.setAdapter(divisionArray);

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            count = position;
            //first spinner item position
            int countrySpinnerPosition = spinnerCountry.getSelectedItemPosition();
            switch (countrySpinnerPosition){
                case 1:
                    //fill data for second spinner
                    fillMasterDivision();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //fill data for second spinner
                    fillDiplomaDivision();
                    break;

            }

        }

        private void fillMasterDivision() {
            divisionArray.clear();
            divisionArray.add("Select Subject:-");
            divisionArray.add("MSC Physics");
            divisionArray.add("MSC Chemistry");

            divisionArray.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        private void fillDiplomaDivision() {
            divisionArray.add("Select Subject:-");
            divisionArray.add("Science");
            divisionArray.add("CTEVT");     
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
```

Please Help.

Comment: It looks like you are not using the correct method call. In the `switch` of `onItemSelected` you are using `fillBachelorDivision` and `fillMasterDivision`.

Comment: @BirendraSingh well how can I use it then...I followed one tutorial from random blog and it worked in there but when I implemented in my app ..It didn't .

Comment: It looks like you meant to call `fillDiplomaDivision` instead of `fillBachelorDivision.`

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question..check now please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to clear the arraylist and notifydatasetchanged in second method too

```
    private void fillDiplomaDivision() {
    divisionArray.clear();
    divisionArray.add("Select Subject:-");
    divisionArray.add("Science");
    divisionArray.add("CTEVT");

    divisionArray.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thaks Diwakar such an easy and nice solution...My bad I missed that line.

Answer (score 2):

There is two mistake in your code.

1. CountrySpinnerPosition will be 0 and 1 for your case so the case should be "case 0" and "case 1".
2. In fillDiplomaDivision method, you have to first clear the list and after adding into the list you have to call notifyDataSetChanged().

Answer (score 0):

First of all ,you are using same `onItemSelected` for both the spinner . so remove `spinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);` and  `spinnerDivision.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);`

After setting data to spinnerCountry use this .

```
spinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
              if(i == 0){
                fillMasterDivision();
              }else{
                fillBachelorDivision();
              }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {


            }
        });
```

and clear your Division array in `fillBachelorDivision()`

Answer (score 0):

See my example:

I have 2 spinners, **firstSpinner** and **secndSpinner**, Second depends of First.

First you have to initialize the spinners in **onCreate** method, and follow steps:

> 1 - You'll insert in first spinner your data ("Master", "Diploma");
>
> 2 - You'll create a function that will update the second spinner with associated values.

```
firstSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        createSecondSpinnerByFirst(position);
     }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter) {
    }
});

private void createSecondSpinnerByFirst(Integer position) {
    List<String> secValues = new ArrayList<>();
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            // insert in secValues array the strings of this condition
            break;
        case 2:
            // insert in secValues array the strings of this condition
            break;
    }

    // usually I use Adapter
    final SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, secValues);
    secndSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

//Code of myAdapter
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> mValues;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context ctx, List<String> values) {
        super(ctx, 0, values);
        context = ctx;
        mValues = values;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Process getItem(int position) {
        return mValues.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return returnLayoutSpinner(context, convertView, mValues.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return returnLayoutSpinner(context, convertView, mValues.get(position));
    }
}

//My function to return the adapter view
private View returnLayoutSpinner(Context context, View convertView, String value) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.spinner_items_view, null);
    }
    TextView txt = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSpinnerItem);
    txt.setText(value, 25);
    return convertView;
}

//spinner_items_view.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/txtSpinnerItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:padding="13dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp">
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void fillDiplomaDivision() {
        //add this line in your code and it solve
        divisionArray.clear();
        divisionArray.add("Select Subject:-");
        divisionArray.add("Science");
        divisionArray.add("CTEVT");     
    }
```